# Where to put phantomjs script in symfony?

Tags: javascript, php, bash, symfony

I want to run bash command `phantomjs myAwesomeScript.js "www.example.com"` from symfony service by using this line:

```
$response = exec("phantomjs $scriptPath $arguments");
```

Where can I put my script `myAwesomeScript.js`? Can I, for example, put this in `app/exec/trollingUrl.js`? or should I put this in another location?

How to correctly get path to this file in symfony?

Answer (score 0):

Install phantomJS with `npm install -globabl phantomjs`

PhantomJS will be installed in you're /usr/local if you're running under a unix system.
It means that il will be accessible on you command line from everywhere

After installing it globably you'll just have to do `<?php exec("phantomjs $scriptPath $arguments");` ?> in any of you're php script without worrying about phantomjs installation path

More information about global instalation here : 
http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/03/23/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation

Comment: I want to precise my question. The path to phantomjs is not a problem, but path to my script in js which will be running by phantomjs ;) Symfony Projects have got their directory structure, and I would want to know where I should to put my script to make correct, simple and clean access to this script in my project ;)